# Symbolically solve a system of coupled second order differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

I have posted a similar question in another forum where the general consensus seems to suggest that it is not possible to symbolic solve a system of coupled second order differential equations with damping (dissipation) and driving forces.

However, I have found in many papers and books writing out analytical formula of the solutions to such coupled equations. So, it must be possible. I just do not know how.

Attached is the system I am trying to solve. Although solving this sort of equation with two masses, no damping (dissipation) and with only one driving force is simple enough, even by hand, it is impossible to do the same for a system with two different damping constants and two driving forces. I have been trying for two weeks now, but could not figure out the solution.

Of course, I could get the numeric solution, but I could not get the same result obtained from Eq. 5. So, I was wondering if someone could help me how to solve this analytically. Any solution to this problem would be of interest.

I am completely new to *Mathematica*, so any example worksheets on this sort of equation would be gratefully appreciated!

[image: Coupled second order diff eqn]

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
eqns = {x1''[t] +  γ1 x1'[t] + ω^2 x1[t] - Ω^2 x2[t] == F/m Exp[-I ωs t],
  x2''[t] +  γ2 x2'[t] + ω^2 x2[t] - Ω^2 x1[t] == 0};
```

Substituting a forced solution

```
eqns2 = eqns /.(rule= {
   x1 ->  Function[t, A1 Exp[-I ωs t]],
   x2 ->  Function[t, A2 Exp[-I ωs t]]})
```

and solving for the amplitude

```
 sol= Solve[eqns2, {A1, A2}] // Flatten // FullSimplify

(*
   {A1 -> (F (ω^2 + ωs (-ωs - I γ2)))/( m (-Ω^4 + (ω^2 + ωs(-ωs - I γ1))(ω^2 + ωs (-ωs-I γ2)))), 
    A2 -> (F Ω^2)/( m (-Ω^4 + (ω^2 + ωs (-ωs -  I γ1)) (ω^2 + ωs (-ωs - I γ2))))}
*)
```

If you want to get the power,

```
F Exp[I ωs t] x1'[t] /. rule /. sol // FullSimplify

(*
==> -(( I F^2 ωs  (-ω^2 + ωs (ωs + I γ2)))/( m (Ω^4 - (ω^2 + ωs (-ωs - 
          I γ1)) (ω^2 + ωs (-ωs - I γ2)))))
*)
```

Comment: You probably want to use `Exp[-I ωs t]` in your solutions

Comment: @SimonWoods good point :-) Well let's see if OP picks on it :-)

Comment: Many thanks Chris, Simon Woods, really appreciated.
Mathematica seems to work very efficiently. In Mathcad I need to write wrong codes and still could not get the analytical solution for x1(t).

I have not tried in Mathematica yet, but in Mathcad a Fourier Transform did not give Eq. 5 (I enter Eq. 4 by hand as I was not able to solve it analytically). 

Could you please try this with Mathematica? Will it work? As I mentioned earlier, I am new to Mathematica, so it take me sometimes to figure out all the commands and syntacs. 

Newin

Comment: I have added the power to my answer.

Comment: Many thanks Chris! Don't have access to the license today, but I will try soon.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
ClearAll[x1, x2, t, γ1, γ2, Ω, ω, ωs, x10, x20]
eq1 = Hold[D[x1[t], {t, 2}]] + γ1 Hold[D[x1[t], t]] + ω^2 x1[t] - Ω^2 x2[t] == 
      F0/m Exp[-I ωs t];
eq2 = Hold[D[x2[t], {t, 2}]] + γ2 Hold[D[x2[t], t]] + ω^2 x2[t] - Ω^2 x1[t] == 0;
eq11 = Release[eq1 /. {x1[t] ->  N1 Exp[-I ωs t], x2[t] ->  N2 Exp[-I ωs t]}];
eq22 = Release[eq2 /. {x1[t] ->  N1 Exp[-I ωs t], x2[t] -> N2 Exp[-I ωs t]}];
sub = {N1 Exp[-I ωs t] -> x1[t], N2 Exp[-I ωs t] -> x2[t]};
Simplify@Solve[{eq11 /. sub, eq22 /. sub}, {x1[t], x2[t]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Made it all Greek letters. Thanks to Halirutan's program and Simon letting me know about it.

Comment: @chris I know. I'd like to use Greek letters, but then when pasting here it becomes hard to read. I do not know how to paste Greek letters here as is as they becomes all `\[ etc....`

Comment: @Nasser, you need Halirutan's [awesome magic buttons](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1044/862)

Comment: @SimonWoods thanks, did not know about this, will try it now to see if I can change it to use Greek letters. It will look better.

Comment: @SimonWoods I need it too! I typed all the greek symbols myself !@

Comment: Many thanks Nasser!